# swing how to override a component

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, swingutilities

I didn't find good title I guess sorry for this,

As you will see bottom I've called

```
ssframe.add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

3 times and if I click the typeButton then unitButton it makes 2 table on the screen. I want to have one table each button clicked, how can I do that.

```
    private class searchListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JButton clickd = (JButton)e.getSource();
            if (clickd==typeButton)
                {
                    try
                        {
                            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(ssframe);
                            showTable1("type",typefield.getText());
                            ssframe.add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        }catch(Exception a)
                        {
                            a.printStackTrace();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Code = 0112");
                        }
                }
            else if (clickd==unitButton)
                {
                    try
                        {
                            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
                            showTable1("unit",unitfield.getText());
                            ssframe.add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        }catch(Exception a)
                        {
                            a.printStackTrace();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Code = 0112");
                        }
                }
            else if (clickd==priceButton)
                {
                    try
                        {
                            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
                            showTable3("price",Integer.parseInt(pricefield.getText()));
                            ssframe.add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        }catch(Exception a)
                        {
                            a.printStackTrace();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error C0de = 0112");
                        }
                }
        }
```

**Edit :** It might help someone I have fixed problem with :

```
model.setRowCount(0);
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: Wait, what are you **trying** to do? Please clarify your goal vs. what you're seeing.

Comment: And why not simply create and show a single JTable, and then if need be swap or alter its TableModel if you want it to show different data (which is what I'm guessing your goal is)?

Comment: And the try-catch block should be factorised (even if the error code was different)

Comment: Have you heard of [cardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this.

1. You could maintain a reference to the `JScrollPane` and replace it's view using `setViewportView`, supplying the table you want to show.  The `JScrollPane` would remain on the frame
2. (Preferably) Update the table model of the table, this will replace the content and update the UI...This means that the `JScrollPane` and `JTable` would be maintained as a single reference and you would then simply change the model.
3. A another solution might be to use a `CardLayout`, which would allow you to switch the views as needed
4. A really, really bad idea would be to remove the previously added components BEFORE you add the new components...

Comment: but table model is always same only sql query is changing ?, sorry I'm newbie and I'm not pro with that.

Comment: So then don't do anything.  Simply update the table, if you never change it, then it will update the table automaticaly.

Comment: @VivianMaya: as mentioned in my comment. Simply change the data held by or swap out table models. It looks like you've got over-kill going on.

Comment: Oh god, I guess I get it, thank you for your attention I'm greatful.

Comment: @VivianMaya: but seriously put a little more effort into providing important detail in your next question. This one looks kind of rushed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfeels sorry for that,I'll do :)